# How to send ipcMessages between Electron and Spectron?

Tags: javascript, electron

I am trying to write some tests for app implemented in Electron using Spectron framework. 
When my application has started properly, I would like to send an event that it is ready. I do something like

In app: I try these two

```
electron.ipcRenderer.send('app-started');
process.send('app-started', "SUCCESS");
```

In test: I try these two

```
beforeEach(function () {
    let pathArgs = path.join(__dirname, '../..');

    app = new Application({
        path: APP_PATH_ELECTRON,
        args: [pathArgs],
        env: {
            TESTING: true,
            NODE_ENV: 'development',
            APPDATA: "C:/tmp"
        }
    });

    return app.start()
        .then(function() {
            assert.equal(app.isRunning(), true);
            client = app.client;
            mainWindow = client.browserWindow;
            ipcRenderer = client.electron.ipcRenderer;
        });
});

it('checks that app-started has been fired', function(done) {

   app.mainProcess.on('app-started', () => {console.log("DONE"); done();});

   app.rendererProcess.on('app-started', () => {console.log("DONE"); done();});

});
```

The function done() is never called :(
I appreciate any ideas what could be wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the even fired before you `it` testcase?

Give this a try to see if the events are firing:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    let pathArgs = path.join(__dirname, '../..');

    app = new Application({
        path: APP_PATH_ELECTRON,
        args: [pathArgs],
        env: {
            TESTING: true,
            NODE_ENV: 'development',
            APPDATA: "C:/tmp"
        }
    });

    app.mainProcess.on('app-started', () => {console.log("DONE"); done();});
    app.rendererProcess.on('app-started', () => {console.log("DONE"); done();});

    return app.start()
        .then(function() {
            assert.equal(app.isRunning(), true);
            client = app.client;
            mainWindow = client.browserWindow;
            ipcRenderer = client.electron.ipcRenderer;
        });
});
```